# bash command to print string in unambiguous form

Tags: bash, string

I am wondering whether there exists a command in `bash` to print a string in a way exposes the special character it contains.

For example, suppose that `a=$'\a\0\b\e'`; does there exists a function to print `\a\0\b\e` literally from `$a`?

The closest I have got so far is by using the `l` command from `sed`:

```
echo "$a"  | sed -n 'l'
```

which returns `\a\000\b\033$`, but the notation is different from that inside `$''`, and it doesn't work if the string contains newlines.

Comment: As variant the `cat -A`. It shows non-printable characters, but in the another form. `echo $'\t\b\e\a' | cat -A` output: `^I^H^[^G`

Comment: Also, `od -c`: `echo $'\t\b\e\a' | od -c`.
Output: `0000000  \t  \b 033  \a  \n`.

Comment: A slightly closer option is `printf %s "$a" | hexdump -c`, which gives me `… \a  \0  \b 033 …`, i.e. just mangles the `\e`.

Comment: Can a string contain `\0`? I don't think so. @Sparhawk, what is your bash version?

Comment: @glennjackman My bash version is zsh (5.4.2).

Comment: zsh is not bash. It's a completely different shell

Answer (score 5):

```
var=$'a b \10 c'
printf %q "$var"
    $'a b \b c'
```

This works in `bash`. I do not know how compatible this is.

Comment: In `bash` 4.4, you can also get the same string via parameter expansion: `${a@Q}`.